# Disable Yoast 14+ for a dynamic archive

Tags: yoast

When using Yoast with WC Vendors Pro it will treat all vendor store pages as the main store archive page. This results in loading the main sites Open Graph data instead of the vendors SEO data that they input.

Up until Yoast 14.0, the code below worked well, but it doesn't work with Yoast 14 anymore. Any ideas on how to revise this since they've deprecated functions?

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpseo_frontend_head_init', 999 );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'enable_wcv_store_seo' );
function enable_wcv_store_seo(){
    if ( !WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpseo_frontend_head_init', 999 );
    }
}
```

Based on a snippet of code found on the Yoast developer portal I was able to target the vendor pages and successfully change the locale (as a test, this doesn't need to be changed).

```
function fleece_wpseo_change_og_locale( $locale ) {
if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
return 'nl_NL';}
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_locale', 'fleece_wpseo_change_og_locale' );
```

I can't find enough documentation to figure out how to target the proper items and know just enough to be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to code an answer and gave it to WC Vendors. This is the more generic option in case someone stumbles onto this. I went a bit deeper into customization on the code I finally implemented:

```
// Change OG title for Yoast on Vendor Pages
function wcv_wpseo_change_og_title( $title ) {
    WC_Vendors::log( $title ); 
    if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        $vendor_id = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );
        $shop_title = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'pv_shop_name', true );
        $og_title = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wcv_seo_fb_title', true );

        if ( ! empty( $og_title ) ) {
            $title = $og_title;
        } else {
            $title = $shop_title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'wcv_wpseo_change_og_title' );

// Change Meta description for Yoast on Vendor Pages
function wcv_wpseo_change_meta_description( $desc ) {
    if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        $vendor_id   = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );
        $shopdesc    = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'pv_shop_description', true );
        $meta_desc   = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wcv_seo_meta_description', true );

        if ( ! empty( $meta_desc ) ) {
            $desc = $meta_desc;
        } else {
            $desc = $shopdesc;
        }
    }
    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'wcv_wpseo_change_meta_description' );

// Change OG description for Yoast on Vendor Pages
function wcv_wpseo_change_og_description( $desc ) {
    if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        $vendor_id   = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );
        $shopdesc    = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'pv_shop_description', true );
        $meta_desc   = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wcv_seo_meta_description', true );
        $og_desc     = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wcv_seo_fb_description', true );

        if ( ! empty( $og_desc ) ) {
            $desc = $og_desc;
        } elseif (! empty( $meta_desc)) {
            $desc = $meta_desc;
        } else {
            $desc = $shopdesc;
        }
    }

    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_desc', 'wcv_wpseo_change_og_description' );

// Change OG image for Yoast on Vendor Pages
function wcv_wpseo_change_og_image ( $image ) {
    if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        $vendor_id   = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );
        $og_image    = get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wcv_seo_fb_image_id', true );

        if (!empty($og_image)) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $og_image );
        }
    }
    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_image', 'wcv_wpseo_change_og_image' );

// Change OG URL for Yoast on Vendor Pages.
function wcv_wpseo_change_og_url ( $url ) {
    if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor_page() ) {
        $vendor_shop = urldecode( get_query_var( 'vendor_shop' ) );
        $vendor_id   = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_id( $vendor_shop );
        $url         = WCV_Vendors::get_vendor_shop_page( $vendor_id );
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_url', 'wcv_wpseo_change_og_url' );
```